# Formatting Contents Of A Variable Length List

Tags: python

Within our application there is a list of common medical conditions:-

```
conditionsList = ['Alzheimers', 'Asmatic', 'Arthtitis', \
   '', '', '' \
    'Cardiovascular', 'Other Musculoskelatal', 'Peripheral Artery Disease']
```

When a patient's details are added or updated there is a second screen where these conditions can be linked to a patient. These are stored in a MySQL database as simple Y/N values. These are then read in:-

```
conditionsVal = [row[i] for row in rows for i in xrange(1, 42)]
```

and a sub-list created

```
 listVal = [historyList[i] for i in xrange(len(historyList)) if historyVal[i] == 'Y']
```

The problem I have is how to format this new list into a sensible printout because any person may have no existing conditions but others may have a dozen or more.

The initial format used is HTML. This is subsequently converted to a PDF,via the utility wkhtmltopdf, for printing/e-mailing if required.The idea is to avoid line wraps, part lines, etc...

Comment: Off topic but: `listVal = [v for v, h in zip(historyList, historyVal) if h == 'Y']` looks a little better.

Comment: "Printout" leaves a lot unspecified.  Do you want to format it as an HTML document?  A PDF?  Plain text on a console?  Part of a GUI with interactive on-screen controls?  Will it always be in monospaced font?

Comment: @jez Requirement for HTML added to question.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a right answer or a wrong answer to this. You can decide how you want to format a list and then write a custom formatting function. Something like:

```
def formatStringList(ls):
    if len(ls) == 0:
        return 'None'
    elif len(ls) == 1:
        return ls[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(ls[:-1]) + ', and ' + ls[-1]
```

Somewhat frivolous test:

```
lists = [[],['Cancer'],['Diabetes','Plague','AIDS','Ingrown Toenails']]

for i,ls in enumerate(lists,start = 1):
    print("Patient " + str(i) + " conditions: " + formatStringList(ls))
```

Output:

```
Patient 1 conditions: None
Patient 2 conditions: Cancer
Patient 3 conditions: Diabetes, Plague, AIDS, and Ingrown Toenails
```

If there are any empty strings in the list you could first filter them out.

You could get more sophisticated and decide on a maximum line length, introducing explicit line breaks (`'\n'`) as needed. Try something. If you aren't happy with it -- tweak it.